# Array reading problems c#

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, forms

i got this code to stock some numbers to a specific array, but the IDE is showing me this error "Use of unassigned local variable 'ascchar'".

```
    private void strtoasc()
    {
        int[] ascchar;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char stg in tbox_string.Text)
        {
            ascchar[i] = Convert.ToInt32(stg);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the array Bounds before assign values to it, If you initialize an array Like this (`int[] someArray=new int[somepositiveInt]`) it will create an array with specified number of indices(all are having `0`). then you can assign values to each index.

```
private void strtoasc()
{
    int[] ascchar=new int[tbox_string.Text.Length];// It will solve the issue
    int i = 0;
    foreach (char stg in tbox_string.Text)
    {
        ascchar[i] = Convert.ToInt32(stg);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you you will get the same output by using the following:

```
 int[] ascchar=tbox_string.Text.Select(c => (int)(c - '0')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

For you immediate problem:

The error is pretty straight forward. You've declared the variable `ascchar`, but you haven't actually assigned anything to it. You need something like `int[] ascchar = new int[somenumber]`. Or if you don't know how large your array needs to be (probably `tbox_string.Text.Length`?), use a `List<int>` instead.

How ever, if your code is intended to give you back the ASCII codes for each character, then you are going about it wrong (that's not how `Convert.ToInt32` works). You can achieve the same thing with something like:

```
var ascchar = Encoding.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(tbox_string.Text);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ohh, thx but i only need the ASCII numbers and the Convert.ToInt32 give me.

Comment: `GetBytes` gives you them. In one go. If it's ASCII they really should be `bytes` and not `int`.

Comment: @jamescaruso [Convert.ToInt32(Char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx) "converts" a UTF-16 code unit as a `Char` to a UTF-16 code unit as an `int`.